# Perguntas sobre Docker estão dentro do escopo do site?

Tags: debate

Estou estudando Docker agora e fiquei na dúvida se posso abrir perguntas aqui sobre o assunto. No stackoverflow em inglês, perguntas sobre o tema são abertas e respondidas normalmente, mas sempre tive a impressão que o SO-en é mais flexível que o SO-pt no que diz respeito ao escopo de peguntas.

Qual a opinião de vocês?

Comment: Depende do bom senso do autor da pergunta. Se for uma pergunta sobre linguagem de programação envolvendo docker não vejo problemas. Mas se for uma pergunta sobre configurações, instalação, compatibilidade, ecossistema docker, virtualização/HYPER-V, comparações de Swam/Kubernets ou qualquer assunto que não faz sentido postar aqui seria melhor a encaminhar a uma site especializado na comunidade [Stack Exchange](https://stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Primeiro as perguntas de Docker geralmente não são exatamente sobre Docker, mas sim sobre um ambiente muito especifico de quem pergunta, o que quase sempre é suporte técnico e não algo sobre como funiona alguma caracteristica do "yml" proprio, na verdade quase todas perguntas que apareceram foram sobre "INFRA" ... Segundo, no SOen a maioria também não é ON, o problema é que o numero de perguntas lá é muito grande para que os moderadores sozinhos consigam dar conta de fechar, e os não moderadores que deveriam ter a consciência de ler o o [help/on-topic] ...

Comment: ... optam por ignorar isso para manter perguntas de helpdesk (suporte técnico) porque geralmente isso atrai score para eles, ou porque nem sabem o que estão fazendo no site. Aqui no site sempre aparece alguém com o argumento, "no SOen é OK e aqui não, pq?", sendo que isso é um equivocou total, é meramente presunção, moderadores são humanos, tem hora de trabalhar, dormir, a comunidade deveria colaborar e tentar entender o que é bom para o site e o que é ON-TOPIC de fato, se comunidade colaborasse e ajudasse seria ótimo ...

Comment: ... tem quem tenta ajudar, mas mesmo veteranos tem usado votos de fechamento de forma errada, perguntas claramente sendo erro de digitação fechadas como "problemas de qualidade". Também tem aqueles que votam em manter aberto perguntas problemáticas só porque desejam responder para levantar score para si mesmos ou porque apoiam transformar o site em um helpdesk, ao invés de uma base de conhecimento. Infelizmente sobra bastante pros mods resolverem, é como se fosse 2% das pessoas fazendo 98% do trabalho, e mais de ~40% das pessoas fazendo o "oposto" e outros ~40% só vem no site para perguntar

Comment: Não estou dizendo que não tem gente que tenta ajudar, eu posso contar nos dedos quem ajuda, apesar de acontecer alguns equívocos do uso do "fechamento" ou do "manter aberto", teve uma dúzia de usuários que já foram reclamar para mim em privado sobre fechamento, coisas simples e óbvias que eu não precisava explicar, pelo menos na teoria não deveria ser preciso, essas pessoas eu tive que explicar mais de uma vez, felizmente um ou outro depois de um tempo e de mais de uma vez me desgastando começaram a buscar "estudar melhor" os tópicos existentes no META para entender os objetivos do site.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento concordo...